# Invalid 'type' (list) of argument in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a list (detList) of determinant values acquired from a list of matrices. The output comes out like this:

```
[[1]]

[1] 1.238624e-15

[[2]]

[1] -5.296541e-15

[[3]]

[1] 1.022744e-15

[[4]]

[1] -7.532619e-16

....
```

But when I try to take the sum of the values it gives me the "Error in sum(detlList): invalid "type' of argument.

So I tried converting it to a vector then taking the sum:

```
finalList<- as.vector(detList)
sum(finalList)
```

But now I get the same error message, "Error in sum(finalList): invalid "type' of argument.

Comment: Try `finalList <- as.vector(detList, mode = "numeric")`

Comment: sum(unlist(detList))